# Working with related documents-population and models

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose-schema

I'm pretty new to these technologies and I don't know if I'm getting it right.

 
I'm trying to print in the table the name of the category instead of the id (ObjectId schema field) of all the documents Category related to the documents Post. But it keeps showing the id. Help please!

**routes/posts.js**

```
Post
        .find({})
        .populate('Category')
        .exec((err, posts) => {
            if (err) return res.json({ error: err })
            posts.category = posts.category.name
            res.render('posts/index', {
                postList: posts
            })
        })
```

**models**

```
let categorySchema = new Schema({
    name: String,
    posts: [{ type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Post' }]
})
module.exports = mongoose.model('Category', categorySchema)

let postSchema = new Schema({
    title: String,
    content: String,
    date: String,
    category: {type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Category' }
})
module.exports = mongoose.model('Post', postSchema)
```

**views/posts/index.pug**

```
tbody
            each post in postList
                tr
                    td #{post.title}
                    td #{post.content}
                    td #{post.date}
                    td #{post.category}  <--HERE IS WHERE I NEED
                                            post.category.name
```

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to populate the field category, since it has a relation in the schema with collection Category, what you need to do is do a populate to the field category, not the collection.

Add this to your models:

```
let categorySchema = new Schema({
    name: String,
    posts: [{ type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Post' }]
})
categorySchema.set('toJSON', {virtuals: true})
module.exports = mongoose.model('Category', categorySchema)

let postSchema = new Schema({
    title: String,
    content: String,
    date: String,
    category: {type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Category' }
})
postSchema.set('toJSON', {virtuals: true})
module.exports = mongoose.model('Post', postSchema)
```

Then, try this:

```
Post.find({})
  .populate({path: 'category'}, {select: 'name'})
  .exec((err, posts) => {
     if (err) return res.json({ error: err })
       posts.category = posts.category.name
       res.render('posts/index', {
          postList: posts
   })
})
```

The select clause is to retrieve just the field name from that collection

For more informacion you can check this link: https://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html

Hope i helped you

Comment: Thanks @Cesar. I've tried but it's not working, still shows the id.

Comment: Updated the question! Please check and try, now it should work @Alvaro

Comment: I changed what you said and it gives me this error: 
_TypeError: utils.populate: invalid path. Expected string. Got type of object_

**When I try this:**
`Post
        .find({})
        .populate('Categoria', 'nombre')
        .exec((err, posts) => {
            if (err) return res.json({ error: err })
            posts.categoria = posts.categoria.nombre
            res.render('posts/index', {
                postList: posts,
                catList: cats
            })
        })`
**I have the following error:**
_TypeError: Cannot read property 'nombre' of undefined_ @cesar

Comment: You need to send it as an object, not to strings, using`( {path: 'categoria' }, {select: 'nombre'})` should work

Comment: Sorry I didn't explain myself well. I used `( {path: 'categoria' }, {select: 'nombre'})` and returns the following error: _TypeError: utils.populate: invalid path. Expected string. Got type of object_  @Cesar